# NAS solution for a synced two geo-location Active - Active

Tags: linux, network-attached-storage, truenas

We are looking for an open source solution to NAS.
We are going to use it on two different server farms with two different geo-location (expected capacity is 10TB).
It should have the following features:

1. Auto Sync between two sites.
2. Active - Active, both sites should be able to read and write .
3. Data encryption.
4. Open source with free community edition.
5. Linux based is preferable.
6. web-GUI is an advantage.
7. Software solution, we have a server with a RAID controller.
   freenas seems to be deprecated, what is the best alternative?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com will be better place to ask